# EF not materializing the parent objects

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I have a strange behavior I never came across while working with EF and SqlServer. I have a Book_Cart that has some related entities like in the picture. lazy loading is turned On

[image]

The funny thing that happens is that the Child records are loaded and executed, while the parent objects are not. While debugging, the Book_Cart entity gets loaded, and all of the attributes, but the parent entities are not.

This was working all of the time, and I had one change done, adding the Transaction table and refreshing the model. Since then I am experiencing the error on the relations that have not been touched.

I have tried removing the entities from the model, the relations and related objects, but nothing works. Tried the whole "clean-rebuild-close" Visual studio process, but noting changes.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Show the relevant code.

Comment: I solved it. I cannot believe what happened.  The context did not lazyLoad the parent records, although it was set to true. After 6 hours of headbanging I tried (out of desperation) to set it to false and back to true, and it started to work. Never heard or experienced this before.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it. I cannot believe what happened.

The context did not lazyLoad the parent records, although it was set to true. 
After 6 hours of headbanging I tried (out of desperation) to set it to false and back to true, and it started to work.

I tried everything, .... restart VS, Windows, revert from GIT and everything that came to my mind, but after 6 hours, LazyLoading property of the Model needed to be set to false, and to true again.

Never heard or experienced this before.